# How can I create a Date from string, ignoring any timezone offsets?

Tags: javascript, date

The server uses +03:00 timezone. It offers me a date in this format: `"2017-04-12T00:00:00+03:00"`

I then create a new Date from this string:

```
options.startDate = new Date("2017-04-12T00:00:00+03:00")
```

But because on the client there is a different timezone, the result is actually:

```
Tue Apr 11 2017 23:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central Europe Daylight Time)
```

This brings me back one day and it's a big deal for me. Is there an elegant way to avoid this and create the same Date and Time in javascript, ignoring the timezone offset?

Comment: The dates represent the same moment in time. Removing the timezone offset means it will represent a different moment in time in each time zone with a different offset.

Answer (score 1):

The date you have in options.startDate is the correct one. What you want is to display it as if you were from the same timezone as the server.
If you now server's timezone in the client script then I would considere using a library like [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/). It would allow you to format date in the timezone you want (GMT for instance, or the one of the server).

Using both moment.js and its plugin timezone code could be :

```
moment("2017-04-12T00:00:00+03:00").tz("America/Los_Angeles").format();
```

Comment: I know it's the correct one from Javascript's point of view, but I need April 12, not April 11

Comment: May I ask why ? People often think they need to display date in same timezone as the server but it's usualy not needed and the reason is they badly configure their server/applications. If you want to do it anyway I gave you the answer :)

Comment: Well, I have a calendar, where users pick a delivery date, for instance. So I set an interval of available dates. The time part of this datetime is irrelevant, I'm only really interested in the actual date.

Comment: Sorry i'm late to answer your question. If I understand well the interval of date you send to your clients correspond to the interval of dates in their timezone, so they should be generated server-side in their timezone. The clean way to solve your issue is therefor to edit your server so it generates dates with the GMT+N related to the client.

Answer (score 0):

I really recommend @VictorDrouin his answer.

But if for some reason you don't want moment.js or fiddle around with it you can use this 'hack'

```
new Date("2017-04-12T00:00:00+03:00".match(/\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}/).pop());
```

What it does it matches the date against given regex date format, and then supplies it to the date parser which makes it a date.

Be careful when supplying it back to the database that you supply it back without timezone offset.

```js
var stringdate = "2017-04-12T00:00:00+03:00";
function getDate(str_date) {
    var matched = str_date.match(/\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}/).pop();
    return new Date(matched);
}
console.log(getDate(stringdate));
```

Comment: The body of your function could be `new Date(stringdate.substr(0,19))`. *Date.parse* and the Date constructor parse strings exactly the same way, the only difference is one returns a time value, the other a string. Also, you will get a different result in Safari and Firefox.

Comment: It could be, but i prefer testing for a specific format. I always wish to validate input. This way no unexpected input will slip by that is unallowed. With my current body you can mandate that only that type of dateformat is acceptable for the function, which removes a lot of ambuigity

Comment: If your *match* doesn't then the above will throw an error, so you should handle that. Even so, there is no need for *Date.parse* so `return new Date(matched)` and you'll still get differences in different browsers.

Comment: It should throw an error. Thats why you have things called specifications, documentation and having behaviours that throw errors when the given specifications are breached.  I hadnt considered the different behaviours by the browsers, ill remove the parse part

Comment: But you don't deal with the error, the script will just fail.

Comment: it is not the purpose of this function to catch the error. the implementing code has to surround it in a try catch when using input from unknow source. the implementing code has to deal with malformed dates. this functions task is to translate ONE type of date format into a `Date` . Any other type is an implementation error and will error out rightly so.

Answer (score 0):

You should never use the Date constructor or Date.parse to parse strings due to browsers differences. Even if you remove the timezone from the string and parse the remainder, e.g.

```js
console.log( new Date('2017-04-12T00:00:00+03:00'.substr(0,19)).toString() );
```

you'll get different results in different browsers (e.g. Firefox and Safari).

If you don't want to use a library, use a simple function (see below). However, if you remove the timezone, the string will represent a different moment in time in each timezone with a different offset.

```js
function parseISOIgnoreTimezone(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  return new Date(b[0], b[1]-1, b[2], b[3], b[4], b[5]);
}

console.log(parseISOIgnoreTimezone('2017-04-12T00:00:00+03:00').toString());
```